# C++11 thread compilation error, deleted copy constructor and std::thread, why?

Tags: c++, c++11

This emits some 100 line error. error: use of deleted function of run_me copy constructor and so on.
So, what's the problem here?

```
#include<thread>
#include<iostream>  
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<chrono>
using namespace std;
//creating thread to print line from file
class run_me {
    ifstream fs;
    public:
    string s;
        run_me(): fs("lliftOff.cpp",ifstream::in) {}
    void operator()(){
        cout<<"hi";
        while(getline(fs,s) ) {
            cout<<s<<endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for (chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    }
    ~run_me() {
        fs.close();
    }
};
int main() {
    thread t1{run_me()};
t1.join();
cout<<"shutting down now"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: File streams close themselves. No need for a destructor.

Comment: istream is not copyable. So I am guessing the default copy constructor is trying to copy ifstream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**THE EXPLANATION**

The Standard mandates that the object, and the parameters, passed to the relevant constructor of `std::thread` must be `MoveConstructible`.

The problem with the given code is that `class run_me` has an implicitly *deleted*  copy/move-constructor since it has a non-copyable member; `std::ifstream fs`.

---

**SOLUTION #1 - CHANGE THE CALL SITE**

To prevent the compiler from trying to copy `class run_me` all we have to do is wrapping the object inside a lambda and initialize our `std::thread` with this said object:

```
std::thread t1 {
  [] { run_me {} (); }
};
```

<sup>**Note:** the above creates a temporary `run_me {}` and calls `operator()` on it inside an anonymous lambda, the temporary `run me {}` will be created when the lambdas function is actually called, not when the lambda is created. When `t1` calls `anonymous-lambda ()` the function scope will be entered, and `run_me {}` will be initialized.</sup>

---

**SOLUTION #2 - CHANGE `class run me`**

Normally we would just add a *move-constructor*  to `class run_me` that would initialize `fs` with a `std::move`d instance of the original `fs`, not really a big issue.

Sadly implementations such as `libstdc++` [hasn't implemented the functionality required to properly move streams](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#iso.2011.specific), this means that we cannot move Standard library streams around, yet.

If you are working with `libstdc++`, or any other implementation that lacks movable streams, we will have to resort to some sort of hack when writing our solution, and I recommend the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class run_me {
    std::unique_ptr<std::ifstream> fs;

    public:
    string s;

    run_me()
      : fs (new std::ifstream ("foo.cpp",ifstream::in))
    { }

    run_me (run_me&& src)
      : fs (std::move (src.fs))
    { }

    void operator()() {
      while(getline(*fs,s) ) {
        cout<<s<<endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for (chrono::seconds(1));
      }
    }

    ~run_me() {
      if (fs) // if we haven't been moved-from
        fs->close();
    }
};
```

Comment: there is a typo, it's `libstdc++` not `stdlibc++`

Comment: @user2485710 fixed, for future reference you can fix such typos yourself by editing the post in question.

Comment: can someone please elaborate on using lambda function to delay creating objects. How does it work?                                         std::thread t1 {
  [] { run_me {} (); }
};

Comment: @vivek see the modified **Note** in **SOLUTION #1**.

Comment: i understood your note. I understand the solution, but not how it works.what does run_me {}() mean?? Can you give me some link which explains it in detail. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @vivek it's equivalent of `run_me temporary_variable = {}; temporary_variable ();`, ie. first a temporary `run_me` is default-initialized, then the `operator()` is called on this temporary.

Answer (score 5):

your `ifstream` implementation lack support for move operation, still deleting copy operation.

You could use a lambda to delay the run_me creation inside the thread

```
std::thread t { [] { run_me{}(); } };
```

If you wants to keep the run_me creation before the thread start, you could use `std::ref`

```
run_me rm;
thread t1{ []( run_me & rm ) { rm(); }, std::ref(rm) };
```

Comment: I don't think you actually need the lambda in your solution. The ‘std::reference_wrapper‘ returned by ‘std::ref‘ is already callable if the wrapped object is callable.